# how to replace elements in a column using pandas

Tags: python, replace, pandas

Given this data frame:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame(data={'words':['w1','w2','w3','w4','w5'],'value':np.random.rand(5)})
>>> a

     value   words
0  0.157876    w1
1  0.784586    w2
2  0.875567    w3
3  0.649377    w4
4  0.852453    w5

>>> b = pd.Series(data=['w3','w4'])
>>> b

0    w3
1    w4
```

I'd like to replace the elements of `value` with `zero` but only for the words that match those in `b`.
The resulting data frame should therefore look like this:

```
    value    words
0  0.157876    w1
1  0.784586    w2
2  0           w3
3  0           w4
4  0.852453    w5
```

I thought of something along these lines: `a.value[a.words==b] = 0` but it's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, just use [pandas.Series.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) instead of `==`:

```
>>> a.value[a['words'].isin(b)] = 0
>>> a
      value words
0  0.340138    w1
1  0.533770    w2
2  0.000000    w3
3  0.000000    w4
4  0.002314    w5
```

Or you can use `ix` selector:

```
>>> a.ix[a['words'].isin(b), 'value'] = 0
>>> a
      value words
0  0.340138    w1
1  0.533770    w2
2  0.000000    w3
3  0.000000    w4
4  0.002314    w5
```

**update** You can see [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) about differences betweed `.ix` and `.loc`, some quotes:

> **.loc** is strictly label based, will raise KeyError when the items are
> not found ...
>
> **.iloc** is strictly integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the
> axis), will raise IndexError when the requested indicies are out of
> bounds ...
>
> **.ix** supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily
> label based, but will fallback to integer positional access. .ix is
> the most general and will support any of the inputs to .loc and .iloc,
> as well as support for floating point label schemes. .ix is especially
> useful when dealing with mixed positional and label based hierarchial
> indexes ...

Comment: Thanks @Roman! Is there a difference in efficiency between .ix and .loc as seen in EdChum's answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.loc` to select the column values you want to assign to:

```
a.loc[a.words.isin(b),'value']=0

Out[10]:

      value words
0  0.065556    w1
1  0.776099    w2
2  0.000000    w3
3  0.000000    w4
4  0.331185    w5
```